# How to pass paremeters with special characters by "Send Parameters With the Request" in JMeter 5.1.1

Tags: parameters, jmeter, httprequest, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0

I need to pass charsets in a string, like `'='` `'/'` `'@'` using "Send Parameters With the Request" from JMeter 5.1 HttpRequest

I try used "RegEx User Parameters" with "Regular Expression Extractor"
Using several custom functions like `__BeanShell(URLDecoder.decode)`, `__unescapeHtml`, `__urldecode`
Decode using "BeanShell PreProcessor" and "JSR223 PostProcessor"
I've searched a lot off manuals and I haven't found the correct answer
If I used variables I have the same result

```
${__BeanShell(URLDecoder.decode("correo@yopmail.com"))}
${__unescapeHtml(correo@yopmail.com)}                    
${__urldecode(correo@yopmail.com)}  // application/x-www-form-urlencoded -- UTF-8
${__urldecode("correo@yopmail.com")}  //UTF-8
```

I expected the request body  `authenticity_token=LzRkqB3M5tXWXZq1axsb9gkhCx3GIAn588RMIkzpRAHqNCkAlCIwMk8pu9jn68Oy1mylI6W/J4AGoE+t1xT15A==&email=correo@yopmail.com`

But the actual is
`authenticity_token=LzRkqB3M5tXWXZq1axsb9gkhCx3GIAn588RMIkzpRAHqNCkAlCIwMk8pu9jn68Oy1mylI6W%2FJ4AGoE+t1xT15A%3D%3D&email=correo%40yopmail.com`

It changes

- `=` to `%3D`
- `@` to `%40`
- `/` to `%2F`

Comment: Welcome to SE.  Please consider formatting your question accordingly so it is easy to read and understand.  Please see here [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)  I'm not sure you will get much help as is.

Comment: Thanks, I tryed.   Please tell me if its better

Answer (score 0):

Uncheck checkbox "URL Encode" to avoid encoding under Parameters tab.

For more ref:-https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request

> Send Parameters With the Request
>
> The query string will be generated
>   from the list of parameters you provide. Each parameter has a name and
>   value, the options to encode the parameter, and an option to include
>   or exclude an equals sign (some applications don't expect an equals
>   sign when the value is the empty string). The query string will be
>   generated in the correct fashion, depending on the choice of "Method"
>   you made (i.e. if you chose GET or DELETE, the query string will be
>   appended to the URL, if POST or PUT, then it will be sent separately).
>   Also, if you are sending a file using a multipart form, the query
>   string will be created using the multipart form specifications. See
>   below for some further information on parameter handling.
>   Additionally, you can specify whether each parameter should be URL
>   encoded. If you are not sure what this means, it is probably best to
>   select it. If your values contain characters such as the following
>   then encoding is usually required.:
>
> ASCII Control Chars Non-ASCII characters Reserved characters:URLs use
>   some characters for special use in defining their syntax. When these
>   characters are not used in their special role inside a URL, they need
>   to be encoded, example **: '$', '&', '+', ',' , '/', ':', ';', '=', '?',**
>   '@' Unsafe characters: Some characters present the possibility of
>   being misunderstood within URLs for various reasons. These characters
>   should also always be encoded, example **: ' ', '<', '>', '#', '%', …**

Output without using encoding
[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! Thats really helpme. So now I need send the information like a submit. The website using the data to send an email and complete a subscription. With the GET Method I cannt doing that, for that reason I tryed with POST. Do you have any idea to resolve that ?

Comment: I suggest, use jmeter recorder to capture the request and then co-relate dynamic parameters.Check this link for recording:- https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html

Comment: Also, check the link. It helps others also.   https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Thanks, I did't but the test plan recorded was created with a Method POST, then present the same problem